# Firebase Cloud Functions deploy error

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy my project from firebase CLI but there is an issue with my functions. This is strange because I had no issues with it four weeks ago. I haven't changed any of my firebase cloud function settings. When I try to run 
  `firebase deploy`  or 
  `firebase deploy --only functions` . 
 
I get this same error:
  `There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.`

Error: HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered.

My cloud functions worked fine before without having to set up a Google App Engine and I can't seem to find anything mentioning the need for a Google App Engine in the Docs.

Comment: Please open a ticket with Firebase support.  Folks on Stack Overflow are unlikely going to be able to diagnose the trouble for you. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: try it again and hope it works :p

Answer (score 5):

Try updating firebase-tools to latest version. That fixed this issue for me.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 5):

For me it was an issue with the cloud resource location.

So just add firestore to your project and choose a location (i.e. europe-west).

Explanation:

After `firebase init` I got an error:

> Error: Cloud resource location is not set for this project but the
>   operation you are attempting to perform in Cloud Firestore requires
>   it. Please see this documentation for more details:
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations

So go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project, choose your project, and click on database and add firestore (or real time database if you prefer). That will also allow your functions to be uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

If your functions use the [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) then yes, you need to create an App Engine project (you don't actually need to deploy a GAE app, tho). From [Dependency on App Engine application](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#dependency_on_gae_name_short_application):

> If you are using a Google Cloud library to access Cloud Datastore,
>   your Cloud project requires an active App Engine application. Open the
>   App Engine [dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine) and confirm your Cloud project has an active
>   App Engine app. Create an App Engine app if needed. The app must not
>   be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

I did the following which resolved the issue for me

> npm i -g firebase-tools

Visited the URL https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine because that was in the response

Answer (score 2):

Check the Google Cloud Status Dashboard if there are service interruptions for the day that your system encountered the issue.

https://status.cloud.google.com/

Comment: Google Stackdriver stopped.

Answer (score 1):

If your functions use the Cloud Datastore, You need to create a Cloud Firestore Database.

Go to the `Firebase dashboard -> Database`
then create new database.

Answer (score 0):

firebase deploy --only functions .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me honeslty it was error in one of the imports names basically my code was the problem everything else was working fine but somehow logs and chatgpt point us to such kinds of tickets.

A javascript compile time error giving this as an error message rather than helping me actually debug the code.

#DebuggingInJavaScript

Answer (score 0):

For me it was also an outdated version of firebase tools.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Resolved the issue for me too as other comments also confirmed.

Keep your Firebase toolchain up to date to see detailed error messages.

In my case, it was the following:

```
Error: Firebase Storage has not been set up on project '...'. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/.../storage and click 'Get Started' to set up Firebase Storage.
```

I tried to deploy without an --only flag but did not have storage set up in my project.